# Redshift queries are 10x slower when using console in comparison with calling them from Java code

Tags: ssl, database-connection, amazon-redshift

We are using Java code to access the Amazon Redshift database (from EC2 instance or local computer) and everything works fine but when we connect with any other type of client on our laptops it is 10 or more times slower. We are located in Europe and Redshift is located in Amazon's Oregon datacentre.

- All type of queries are affected
- It doesn't matter what client are we using (psql, SQL Workbench ..) except directly from code

Can it be related to SSL encryption or smth on the network layer?

If you need more data, please ask.

The same question was asked to Amazon support, they said that they fixed it and after a week it returned to normal state. This is obviously a common problem but it hasn't anything to do with network latency. Is there a way to avoid it. How do you access your production data?

Comment: From where are you connecting to the Redshift cluster? From EC2 instances, your laptop, geographic region?

Comment: EDIT: @Guy I answered your questions in the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody facing same issue: you are not the first. The problem is network latency. It's funny but Redshift calculates query execution time till last row accepted by your client. Just dismiss it.

Comment: What should be expected query execution time? If you compare 3/30 seconds query, 27 seconds can not possibly be network latency. Anything above 30 seconds for simple queries doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Take a look on "sql round trips" subject. The query with less joins and smaller result set has to suffer less from network issues. By the way the networking in RDBMS is the main reason to use stored procedures, that still unsupported by RedShift. Anyway there is nothing to do.

Comment: @YuriLevinsky "Redshift calculates query execution time till last row accepted by your client" Is that true if you look at the execution time from elapsed column in SVL_QLOG table, or is it just for the web console client reported time?